# how to store large output in a variable in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, kubernetes

whenever i hit this command
`$APIGEECTL_HOME/apigeectl check-ready -f overrides/overrides.yaml`
it will give me logs like this
`Error: ready check failed: one or more pods is not ready: [{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-cassandra-default-0","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-cassandra-schema-setup-seraphic-spider-45752e3-qqkdp","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-cassandra-user-setup-seraphic-spider-45752e3-6nblk","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-logger-apigee-telemetry-gwzc4","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-mart-seraphic-spider-45752e3-142-35llw-54v2g","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-metrics-apigee-telemetry-app-142-k3l39-phct6","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-metrics-apigee-telemetry-proxy-142-kgp0o-dtfz9","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-runtime-seraphic-spider-test-252850d-142-rwjcy-f7gsx","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-synchronizer-seraphic-spider-test-252850d-142-dfe1rld2qw","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-udca-seraphic-spider-test-252850d-142-7acpg-cl2r9","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"},{"namespace":"apigee","pod":"apigee-watcher-seraphic-spider-45752e3-142-r9pgy-8r6c2","reason":"ContainersNotReady","status":"False"}]`
it`s big logs is shown only pods are not ready they are trying to be ready
so i want to store this logs in a variable and run a loop like when all pods are created then this command show a message like "All pods are ready" means whenever command got this message loop will be terminate

Comment: You can probably check for strings like `Error` and if not present that means everything is fine yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch the standard output of a program, do something like

```
pout=$(prog)
```

To catch the standard error of a prorgram, do

```
perr=$(prog 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

To catch both into different variables, do

```
errout=tmp.$$
pout=$(prog 2>$errout)
perr=$(<$errout)
rm $errout
```

This gives you the respective output as a scalar. If you want to have it in an array, you do something like

```
pout=( $(prog) )
```

etc.

Comment: In your case prog is referred to command like this pout=( $($APIGEECTL_HOME/apigeectl check-ready -f) )

Comment: @RohanKumarJangid : You can run whichever program you want....

Comment: perr=$(prog 2>&1 >/dev/null) this is working fine, could you please tell me how i put this into a loop like hit this command again again and whenever the respose of that command got "all container are ready " then it will  be break from loop else hit that commands again and again

Comment: If you want to iterate over all the lines of the program, I suggest that you store it into an array, not a scalar. If you don't know how to iterate an array, please ask a new question. In [so], different themas should go into different questions, and storing the output of a program is somewhat unrelated to the problem of itertaing an array, even if you happen to need both in a single script.

Comment: but pout=( $(prog) ) => pout=( $($APIGEECTL_HOME/apigeectl check-ready -f overrides/overrides.yaml) )
this is not working in my case whenever i print pout it won`t print anything

Comment: It is an array. How did you print it? And: You are catching here stdout. In your previous comment, you were catching stderr. Are you sure that you **know** what you are doing here?

Comment: bro stderr is like when my command getting any issue command is working fine it is just logs that are showing in my question it is not stderr it is just stdout and i have to store this and iterate over that commands till i got output as "All container are ready"

Comment: If it's really stdout, great. I just wondered because in your earlier comment you said: _perr=$(prog 2>&1 >/dev/null) this is working fine,_, from which I conclude that you wanted to catch stderr, not stdout.

Comment: so according to you if it is stderr so how can I store stderr in a variable

Comment: According to what **you** wrote, I conclude it is stderr, but this is something you definitely need to find out first. As how to store it, I described in my answer.